# How to provide translations for field names with Symfony2/Doctrine2 via REST?

Tags: rest, symfony, doctrine-orm

We have a backend built on FOSRestBundle (JMSSerializer) based on Symfony2/Doctrine2.

Our API e.g. delivers for some entity something like: **'valid_from': '2015-12-31'** in a REST/JSON response.

Our AngularJS frontend consumes this REST API and e.g. presents some form to the user:

**Valid from: 31.12.2015**

Now I am wondering what's the best way to have a central/or maintainable place for a mapping like: 
**an English label for field key 'valid_from' is 'Valid from'**

To my understanding all Translatable extensions for Doctrine (like Gedmo Kpn etc.) are to translate content (e.g. 'category' = 'Product' in English and = 'Produkt' in German) but not schema.

And of course I cannot change/adapt the field key to the language because it's the identifier for the frontend.

What I thought so far:

1. **Use some mapping file between field_key, language_key and
   translation on frontend.**

Issue here is that the frontend needs to know a lot and ideally any change in the API can be done thoroughly by the backend developers.

2. **Use some mapping file between field_key, language_key and
   translation on frontend.**

As we use annotations for our Entity model and JSMSerializer I'd need to open a totally new space for just translation information. Doesn't sound too convincing.

3. **Create custom annotation with properties**

Current idea is to use custom annotation (which would be cacheable and could be gathered and provided as one JSON e.g. to the frontend) with my entity properties.

That means any backend developer could immediately check for translation keys at least as soon as the API changes.

Something like:

```
 @ORM\Column(name='product', type='string')
 @FieldNameTranslation([
      ['lng'=> 'de-DE'],['text']=>'Product'],
      ['lng'=> 'en-En'],['text']=>'Produkt'])
```

A further idea could be just to provide some translation key like:

```
 @FieldNameTranslation(key='FIELD_PRODUCT')
```

and use Symfony's translation component and have the content in translation yml files.

What is your opinion? Is there any 'best in class' approach for this?